# SampleSyncAdapter: getting the cloud webserver portion working

Tags: android

OK, I've gotten the SampleSyncAdapter example working, and I mostly understand it.

However, what I don't understand is the other half: how to get the cloud webserver working. I know there's some Python scripts and yaml files included in the example, but I don't know how to get them working, and I've found few hints other than "it's RESTful".

So I have a Debian box on the net, and I install Apache and probably mod-python, put the example scripts in a content directory, aaaaaand... then what? Even the slimmest of recipes would help.

Comment: i think that this server side code in example is for google AppEngine

Answer (score 0):

First off, you'll need to have [django installed](http://jeffbaier.com/articles/installing-django-on-an-ubuntu-linux-server/) to do this, and [google app engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html) installed. Launch the webapp from google appengine and then point your browser to the url show in the appengine applicaiton.